# Flutter share bloc between pages

Tags: api, flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a basic flutter app with 2 pages and 1 bloc.

- The home page displays a list of users (only 2 attributes)
- When a user-item is clicked, a detail page displays all attributes

The user data is fetched using a bloc which emits 2 states

- AllUsersLoadedState from the api domain.com/users
- UserLoadedState from the api domain.com/users/id

Because both home page and detail page is using the same bloc in their BlocBuilder when I navigate to the detail page and hit the back button, the home page is crashed.

Any way to handle it without writing 2 individual bloc?

Comment: Could you share your event, state and bloc files

Comment: Share your code, the back button shouldn't interfere with anything on your case as the Bloc that you described don't depend on navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a BLoC between screens, then you should create the BLoC in such a way that it won't be destroyed while those 2 screens are active.

One way of doing this is to provide the BLoC using the [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, or as an `InheritedWidget`. If you use `Provider` then on each screen you just ask for the BLoC using `Provider.of<MyBloc>(context)`. You will have to read more about `Provider` to learn how to use it.

Another way is passing the BLoC as a variable to your widget's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the issue.
Because both pages were using the same bloc they would rebuild on both states while the intended behavior was for the home page to rebuild only on AllUsersLoadedState and detail page to rebuild only on UserLoadedState.

So when I navigate to the detail page and a UserLoadedState is received the home page didn't know how to handle the state and would crash.

The solution is to use the condition parameter in the bloc builder to skip rebuilding on an unwanted state.